# Parsing JSON with Python: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, json

I'm using Python to parse through some JSON data for specific values. Specifically I want to pull the following:

- author_id
- created_at
- public

The Python code looks like;

```
import json
import requests

# Set the request parameters
url = 'https:<MYURL.json'
user = 'MY_USER'
pwd = 'MY_PWD'

# Do the HTTP get request
response = requests.get(url, auth=(user, pwd))

# Check for HTTP codes other than 200
if response.status_code != 200: 
print('Status:', response.status_code, 'Problem with the request. Exiting.')
exit()

# Decode the JSON response
data = response.json()

# Print each value

field_list = data['audits']
for fields in field_list:
print(fields['author_id'])
print(fields['created_at'])
print(fields['events']['public'])
print '\n'
```

My code errors with:

```
File "get_ticket_updates.py", line 27, in <module>
print(fields['events']['public'])
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

I get that the value of public is a string and it needs to to be integer so, how can I work with this?

The data looks like:

```
{

"audits": [
    {

        "id": 20994687984,
        "ticket_id": ####,
        "created_at": "2014-09-15T16:30:11Z",
        "author_id": 312016568,
        "via": {
            "channel": "email",
            "source": {
                "from": {
                    "address": "email@domain.com",
                    "name": "user name",
                    "original_recipients": [
                        "email@domain.com",
                        "email@domain.com"
                    ]
                },
                "to": {
                    "address": "email@domain.com",
                    "name": "My Portal"
                },
                "rel": null
            }
        },
    },
 {
        "id": 20994845144,
        "ticket_id": ####,
        "created_at": "2014-09-15T16:32:18Z",
        "author_id": 233915468,
        "via": {
            "channel": "web",
            "source": {
                "from": {},
                "to": {},
                "rel": null
            }
        },
        "events": [
            {
                "id": 20994845154,
                "type": "Comment",
                "author_id": 233915468,
                "body": "<SOME TEXT>",
                "public": true,
                "attachments": []
            },
```

Comment: *Listen* to the error message. *Find the cause* (eg. expression) resulting in the error. *Reconcile* the believed and actual values/state/behavior.

Comment: Minimally reproducible: `l = []; l['foo']`; the error has *naught to do with parsing* the JSON, but instead is caused by the *incorrect usage* of the resulting Python object-graph.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Insted of `fields['events']['public']` it should be `fields['events'][0]['public']`

Comment: If I could bump this answer more than once I would. Thank you for returning my sanity.

Answer (score 5):

```
print(fields['events'][0]['public'])
```

`fields['events']` is a list so you need to use `['events'][0]` to access the dict inside the list.

Answer (score 3):

It's exactly as the error says. `fields['events']` is a list, so you can't index it with `['public']`. You need to iterate through the values, each of which is a dictionary.

```
for event in fields['events']:
    print event['public']
```

Comment: there is only one dict inside

Comment: In that sample data, yes. But clearly not always, otherwise it wouldn't be a list in the first place.