# How to set/query a list item with a dynamic variable?

Tags: python, json

Given the following JSON list...

file:

```
 [   {
     "red": "apple",
     "yellow": "lemon",   } ]
```

I'd like to do the following in Python and have it return `'apple'`:

```
[...]  
color = red
fruits = json.loads(file.read())
return fruits[color]
[...]
```

I of course get the following error when I try:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON with Python: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855276/parsing-json-with-python-typeerror-list-indices-must-be-integers-not-str)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `fruits[0][color]`. You're currently indexing the outer list, not the inner dictionary.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want `fruits` to be a dictionary you should specify that when loading the file, for example:

```
[...]  
color = red
fruits = json.loads(file.read())[0]
return fruits[color]
[...]
```